# Regular Expression that matches a number with commas for every three digits

Tags: python, regex

It needs to match these

- '42'
- '1,234'
- '6,368,745'

but not the following:

- '12,34,567' (which has only two digits between the commas)
- '1234' (which lacks commas)

I been using site such as http://www.regexpal.com/ to test out expressions.

I tried

- `^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*$`
- `(\d{1,3},)*(\d{1,3})$`
- `([0-9]{1,3},)*([0-9]{1,3})$`
- `[0-9]{1,3}((,[0-9]){1,3})*`

but it doesn't work.

Could someone explain what's wrong with my attempts and an model answer?

Comment: I think you need a lookahead. I have never done one of them so I can't tell you how it would be right, but it may be the keyword you needed.

Comment: In what testcase first one doesn't work, i.e. `^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*$`?

Comment: http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=95371 - first one works

Comment: Instead `^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*$` works. I think the problem is you don't set the multiline mode.

Comment: Show your Python code. Always test the regex in the original environment before asking a regex question.

Comment: Thanks for replies everyone. Problem was I didn't enable multiline mode on these regex test sites!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
^([0-9]{1,3})(,[0-9]{3})*$
```

Should do what you are after. 
I usually use http://pythex.org/ to test python regex strings.

Comment: This is basically same as `^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*$` from question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following pattern will fit your need.
It allows the accepted numbers to be preceded by a comma not preceded by a digit, and to be followed by a comma not followed by a digit.

```
pati = ('(?<!\d,)(?<!\d)'
        '('
        '\d{1,3}'  '(?:,\d\d\d)*'
        ')'
        '(?!,\d)(?!\d)'
        )

rgx= re.compile(pati)
```